# MySQL consulta con 2 tablas y 2 condiciones

Tags: mysql

Necesito obtener todos los autores que tengan 5 obras o más y que sean mayores de 50 años.

No consigo ver la manera de contar los autores que tienen 5 o más obras... no sé si es una condición más en el where (con una consulta anidada) o tengo que hacer uso de GROUP BY/HAVING.

TABLAS:
Autor (#id, nombre, apellido, edad)
Obra (#id, titulo, fecha, -id_autor)

CONSULTA:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM autor a, obra o
WHERE a.id = o.id_autor
AND a.edad > 50
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar, tu consulta no es estándar, no pasaría la restricción del *`only_full_group_by`*. Aunque ciertas versiones de MySQL permiten eso, no es bueno que escribas este tipo de consultas permisivas.

Dicho eso, estás bien encaminado, sólo tienes que poner la `edad` en el `SELECT` y agregarla como condición en el `HAVING`, pero usando *mayor o igual*, es decir **`>=`**.

Por último, usaré `JOIN` explícito, porque es más claro.

Aquí te dejo un fiddle completo:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE autor (
  id INT,
  nombre VARCHAR(250),
  edad INT
);

CREATE TABLE obra (
  id INT,
  titulo VARCHAR(250),
  id_autor INT
);

INSERT INTO autor VALUES 
(1,'Autor 1', 25),
(2,'Autor 2', 50),
(3,'Autor 3', 35),
(4,'Autor 4', 65);

INSERT INTO obra VALUES 
(1,'Obra 1',1),
(2,'Obra 2',2),
(3,'Obra 3',3),
(4,'Obra 4',4),
(5,'Obra 5',2),
(6,'Obra 6',3),
(7,'Obra 7',2),
(8,'Obra 8',1),
(9,'Obra 9',2),
(10,'Obra 10',1),
(11,'Obra 11',2),
(12,'Obra 12',1),
(13,'Obra 13',1),
(14,'Obra 14',1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    a.id,  
    MAX(a.edad) as edad
FROM 
    autor a
INNER JOIN obra o ON a.id = o.id_autor
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5 AND edad >= 50;
```

| id | edad |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 50 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/syPaDYsRRfP6rhnP4QfB6z/0)

Comment: ¿Hay algún motivo para usar "MAX(a.edad) as edad" en el SELECT? A no ser que se me escape algo, no es necesario hacer uso de la función MAX ahí... Gracias por tu respuesta, A.Cedano ;)

Comment: @capovawi sí, es para cumplir con el estándar `only_full_group_by`. En una consulta de agrupación, debes indicar al manejador qué hacer con aquellas columnas que podrían arrojar más de un resultado y la forma de hacerlo es mediante funciones de agrupación o de agregación.

Comment: Si en el fiddle pruebas a cambiar MAX(a.edad) AS edad` por `a.edad` verás que la consulta no funcionará, porque en ese entorno el `only_full_group_by` está activado, y así debería ser. Quizá en tu entorno funciona porque está desactivado, pero eso es pésimo, porque te puedes habituar a escribir consultas no estándar y erróneas en otros contextos. Aparte de eso, el gran problema es que no tienes en control exacto sobre el resultado que arrojará una consulta permisiva a ese nivel.  Aquí sabes que traerá el valor máximo de todos los valores posibles.